# is there a way to make Hibernate convert UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type data to String for H2 DB while querying?

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, uniqueidentifier

We are using H2 DB for Integration tests/local development and Azure SQL Server for the stage environment. There are instances where a query that works fine for SQL Server, doesn’t work for H2 DB and vice-versa.

One such instance is when using **uniqueidentifier** data type for the UUID type column in SQL Server. The JPA/Hibernate is compatible with uniqueidentifier data type and maps well with Java.util.UUID type. On Save, the UUID gets stored properly in UUID format. On fetch (select query), the UUID is returned as a string, which can be converted to a UUID with UUID.fromString() API.

But that’s not the case with H2 DB. Automatically, The Hibernate creates the column with type as Binary(255) for Java.util.UUID attribute. On Save, the UUID gets stored as non UUID format (Hex format). On fetch(select query) it comes as Byte[].

Thus code breaks where you try to transform a query resultSet to a Java object.

We tried using @Column(columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier") annotation on UUID type attribute in Entity. With this change, now the data type of the column is changed to uniqueidentifier. However, on fetch, the Hibernate still converts it to Byte[].

Entity:

```
@ToString
@Table(name="TASK")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
}
```

Query & Transformation:

```
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT id, name from task where id=?");
        query.setParameter(1,id);
        List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
        Task task = null;
        for (Object[] row: resultList) {
            Integer rowIndex =0;
                                                    /***Code fails here***/
            task = Task.builder().id(UUID.fromString((String) row[rowIndex])).name((String) row[rowIndex+1]).build();
        }
```

Other Details:

```
H2 version: 1.4.200
Hibernate version: 5.4.28.Final
```

I want to know if there is a better way to handle this? or am I missing something in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a native query? Just use a JPQL/HQL query:

```
TypedQuery<Task> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t from Task 
 t where t.id=?", Task.class);
query.setParameter(1, id);
List<Task> tasks = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to use compatibility modes with h2 db url like below:

1. To use the MS SQL Server mode, use the database URL jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE. Do not change value of DATABASE_TO_LOWER and CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS after creation of
2. To use the IBM DB2 mode, use the database URL jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=DB2;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH or the SQL statement SET MODE DB2.

For more details https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility